# My website is slow and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: time, web, load

It's been 2 days and I think i might have to kill myself.

My website for some reason suddenly started taking way way wayyyy to long to load.
I have cloudflare enable on my domain to cache content so my site can load faster, I've tried turning it off, but my site is still taking forever to load.

I've used pingdom(http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dFvagb/http://streamaton.com/) and according to the results it shows that the domain itself is taking to much time to load(whut?).
I've tried visiting other section of my site like my admin panel and the site loads up pretty fast.

I have no idea how to pin point the root of this problem.

Comment: I forgot to add: For some random reason the site worked pretty fine last night.

Comment: Try something like NewRelic to see where your code is slow. Maybe it's your DB and you're doing big queries without hitting indexes. Check your analytics if you have a lot of users online at the same time all of a sudden. There's an endless list of things you can do before asking a vague question here. What are we supposed to do with a pingdom trace?

Answer (score 0):

it depends a bit on the circumstances: 
Could the case be that you have much higher load than usually?

If not, did you perform any code changes that might be responsible for that change?

it could also be the case that the server your website is on is under unusual high load or in some weird half-dead state. Sending a mail to your ISP asking them to check your server might be a good idea in any case.

Comment: I haven't made any big changes on my code, but I think i'm going to restore a backup and see what happens. And now my site is either showing half the content before it stop or just straight up gives me blank page for no reason.